# non-intersecting lines inside a projective quadric

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In his book "Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms" D. Cox writes:

[image]

Indeed, i can see that if $b \neq b'$ then $L_b$ does not intersect with $L_{b'}$.
But does that not contradict the fact that two lines always intersect in
projective space? What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two lines *in the projective plane* intersect. This is a quadric surface in $\Bbb P^3$. (Think of the saddle surface $z=xy$ in $\Bbb R^3$. Note that if you fix $x=c$, you get a line $(c,y,cy)\subset\Bbb R^3$. For different values of $c$, these lines are disjoint.)

Comment: Two lines inside a quadric in $\mathbb{P}^3$ are not two lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$? Then we use the word "line" for two different things?

Comment: Sure, they're lines in $\Bbb P^3$. But most lines in $\Bbb P^3$ are skew, i.e., do not intersect. Only in $\Bbb P^2$ must they intersect.

Comment: Ah, ok...I thought there was a general statement that two lines in $\mathbb{P}^n$ always intersect. Thanks.

Comment: A utility pole near a railway track gives an example of lines, namely the pole and a rail, which do not intersect in usual affine space $\mathbb A^3$,  and this is fortunate for the train! They don't intersect (once completed)  in projective space $\mathbb P^3$  either since they are not parallel .

Comment: Nice, @Georges :) +1

Comment: @Manos Things (not just linear things, although that's easier to prove) intersect in projective space when the dimensions work out. $1 + 1 = 2$ and all that.